# Make column editiable in pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

How to unlock the fields in pgadmin4 so I can insert/update column directly threw pgadmin4 **Data Output** result. 
Please refer below image displaying lock icon in each field

[image]

I want result like below which has icon of a pencil which shows that the field is editable.

[image]

I have given all the permission on the table.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Give your table a primary key column.  Otherwise, pgAdmin4 has no way to communicate to the database which row you are trying to edit.

Comment: I've done this, but the locks are still there @jjanes

Comment: Refresh your table to get the updated table information.

Answer (score 3):

We have to make sure we have selected the primary key at tables properties level (right click on your table).
You can do that inside table properties column section:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It happens if I do a join with me, try seperately running the queries without joins for the columns that you want to edit.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your table columns have a black key icon is because the `id column is not a primary key`, maybe because you accidentally deleted it. I encountered that in hasura when I accidentally deleted the primary key id, after resetting it. went back to normal in postgres. You also just need to reset id as primary key in postgres